# A function similar to a rotated-sin

Tags: geometry, functions

I would like to find a mathematical function like the one I sketched below. My first idea was to rotate a sin function, but now I don't think that would work because I would like the function to be well-defined so that for one x, there is only one y.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rotated sine will work as long as the rotation ($45°$) does not exceed the maximal slope ($1$). Then the curve will sometimes be vertical, but not backward.

This leads to the following Cartesion equation: $y+x=sin(y-x)$. Unfortunately, you can't put it in an explicit form $y=f(x)$.

A workaround is to use a parametric equation, giving you points $(x,y)$ as a function of $t$.
$$x=\sin(t)-t\\y=\sin(t)+t.$$

[image]

You can control the amplitude of the oscillations by adding a coefficient to the sine.

[image]

Comment: thank you for very clear answer, Yves. If you have the effort and interest, can you explain why when I add coefficent to sin of more than 1 the graph gets "strange"? I understand to get your second graph the coefficient should be less than 1 but I do not see the mathematical intuition. Second, I plan to review these parameterizations in basic geography book but if you have any specific recommendations for back ground, please let me know. Thank you again Yves.

Comment: Rotate your screen by $45°$: what you see is a standard sinusoid and you can play with its amplitude. If the slope exceeds $1$ (i.e. when $|a|>1$, the curve is no more univocal). Geography ??

Comment: I see. Sorry, I meant top put the geometry. I suppose I should add English in addition :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation

Answer (score 2):

Try 
$$y(x):=-x + a + \frac{1}{b}\sin(2\pi x)$$

Here is a plot of this $y(x)$ function with $a=b=4$.

[image]